# Explain the following Rotation (the matrix transformation)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, rotations

What is the difference of Rotating counterclockwise by origin by $\theta$ and rotating clockwise by origin through $\theta$? And what are their formulas?
I know that for counterclockwise rotation, the formula is

$$T = \left(\begin{array}{rr}\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta)\\\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) \end{array}\right)$$

But what is the formula for clockwise rotation?

Comment: To rotate in the opposite direction, replace $\theta$ with $-\theta$, and note that $\cos(-\theta) = \cos(\theta)$ and $\sin(-\theta) = -\sin(\theta)$. Alternatively, you could explicitly calculate the inverse of $T$. This is easy since $T$ is an orthogonal matrix.

Answer (score 0):

You have a mapping $T:[0,2\pi) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$.  If you want to rotate clockwise, then just rotate by $-\theta$ radians.  So
$$
S(\theta)=\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
cos(\theta) & sin(\theta)\\
-sin(\theta) & cos(\theta) \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$
where I'm using the fact that $cos(.)$ is an even function and $sin(.)$ is an odd function.

Answer (score 0):

A clockwise rotation by angle $\theta$ is the inverse of a counterclockwise rotation by angle $\theta$ so you need to invert the original matrix $$\boldsymbol T:=\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{bmatrix}.$$
Noting that this is an orthogonal matrix (all matrices associated with rotations are orthogonal), i.e., $\boldsymbol T^\intercal\boldsymbol T=\mathbf I$ (the identity matrix), the inverse is $$\boldsymbol T^{-1}=\boldsymbol T^\intercal=\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta&\sin\theta\\-\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Bungo's answered it before me. Sorry, I just saw your comment after I wrote it up...